# The entries of dictionaries within the list becomes same

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to store data like

```
list = [
    {
        "student_name": "",
        "Age": "",
        "email": ""
    },
    {
        "student_name": "",
        "Age": "",
        "email": ""
    },
]
```

the dictionary is stored in a variable called dictionary
but there is an error, the data in dictionaries in each index are updated to data which are input in last

This is the error
[image]

code:

```
a = 2
list = []
dictionary = {
    "student_name": "",
    "Age": "",
    "email": ""
}
for i in range(a):
    dictionary["student_name"] = input("enter student name: ")
    dictionary["Age"] = input("enter student age: ")
    dictionary["email"] = (dictionary["student_name"].replace(" ", "") + dictionary["Age"] + "@mycampus.com").lower()
    list.append(dictionary)

print(list)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are appending same entry. So first, second entry both point to same dictionary. So whatever the value is of dictionary, that will be for both entries. You can think of this as pointing to same object.

```py
for i in range(a):
    dictionary = dict()
    dictionary["student_name"] = input("enter student name: ")
    dictionary["Age"] = input("enter student age: ")
    dictionary["email"] = (dictionary["student_name"].replace(" ", "") + dictionary["Age"] + "@mycampus.com").lower()
    list.append(dictionary)

print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't use the built-in `list` as a variable name.

Since you create `dictionary` outside the `for` loop, you only create one `dict`, which you then overwrite at every iteration of the loop. Instead, create a new `dict` at every iteration and append that to your list.

Try this:

```
l = []

for i in range(2):
    d = dict()
    d["student_name"] = input("enter student name: ")
    d["Age"] = input("enter student age: ")
    d["email"] = (d["student_name"].replace(" ", "") + d["Age"] + "@mycampus.com").lower()
    l.append(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use `list` as a variable name because it is an in-built function
2. You should reset the dictionary after every iteration

Try this -

```
a = 2
mylist = []

for i in range(a):
    dictionary = {} # Or dictionary = dict()
    dictionary["student_name"] = input("enter student name: ")
    dictionary["Age"] = input("enter student age: ")
    dictionary["email"] = (dictionary["student_name"].replace(" ", "") + dictionary["Age"] + "@mycampus.com").lower()
    mylist.append(dictionary)

print(mylist)
```